# lvmetad is not coming up by default at boot time with systemd. Process starts if started manually

Tags: linux, systemd, lvm

"lvm2-lvmetad.service" is dependent on "lvm2-lvmetad.socket". This socket creates one ListenStream which is not being creating at boot time. can someone explain how this listen stream gets created ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this service, but if you do `systemctl status lvm2-lvmetad` and it says `Loaded: masked (/dev/null)`, then you can try unmasking and enabling it:

```
sudo systemctl unmask  lvm2-lvmetad
sudo systemctl enable  lvm2-lvmetad
```

`systemctl status lvm2-lvmetad.socket` should show you it is `Loaded: loaded ...; enabled; ...`

Comment: thanks @meuh. systemctl helped in this case. It creates symbolic link which is required to start this service.